# Could Stirling Engines work on sunlight alone?

Tags: engines, solar-power, reaction-wheel, experiment, cooling

With the heated side facing the sun and the rest in its own shade, could two contra-rotating Vacuum Stirling Engines and flywheels, in tandem, accumulate torque, to power a reaction wheel? Can the heat from an ion engine be used to provide forward momentum this way?

Comment: If the first will work, then why can't the heat from an engine also provide forward momentum instead of sunlight?

 
I know the spinning wheel doesn't move you but the acceleration and deceleration of two contra-rotating wheels can.

Comment: No, adding up torques can't produce a linear acceleration, just a net torque on the whole ship.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Could Stirling Engines work on sunlight alone? With the heated side facing the sun and the rest in its own shade, could two contra-rotating Vacuum Stirling Engines and flywheels, in tandem, accumulate torque, to power a reaction wheel?

Yes.

> Can the heat from an ion engine be used to...

power a Stirling engine? Yes!

> ...provide forward momentum this way?

No.

Let's assume your spacecraft start out with zero translational momentum and zero angular momentum. That's pretty much the end of the story.

**You can rotate your spacecraft** since it has moving internal parts like cats do. For more on that see Destin's *stunt cat* Gigi, as well as cats in simulated zero gravity do it in the YouTube video [Slow Motion Flipping Cat Physics | Smarter Every Day 58](https://youtu.be/RtWbpyjJqrU) viewable below.

Even though your spacecraft's net angular momentum about its center of mass remains at zero, parts can move with respect to other parts, and those movements include relative rotations.

**You can not** propel your spacecraft forward or backward. Spinning wheels will not move you anywhere, unless you are on a road, or in an atmosphere.

**However you will likely start to move very slowly** because the photons you are reflecting, absorbing and re-radiating have a small amount of momentum. This is not related to any particular motion of any internal parts moving parts. You've simply become a [very weak solar sail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail). For every "hot" photon from the Sun you'll radiate many "cooler" photons. Conservation of energy means $E_{in} = E_{out}$ and the momentum of a photon is just $E/c$, so if you radiate into a hemisphere you won't be able to completely cancel your absorbed momentum, and of course some light will be reflected back adding even more momentum.

Comment: If a the first will work, then why can't the heat from an engine also provide forward momentum instead of sunlight?

Comment: @Xaddell total momentum of a system is a conserved quantity. You can't convert pure energy in a change of momentum, you can use energy to eject some propellant at high speed in order to accelerate you in the opposite direction, but the total momentum of the combined centre of mass (you+the propellant) will be unchanged. In a standard rocket, the fuel is both a source of energy and the reaction mass; with a different source of energy you still need to eject some reaction mass in order to accelerate.

Comment: Fundamentally, a reaction wheel moves one side of the craft "forwards" by moving the other side "backwards", i.e. using it as reaction mass. But both sides remain coupled together. To get forward momentum, you have to use *something else* as reaction mass, and let go of it, i.e. lose it.

Comment: @Xaddell I've slightly modified the answer. Sunlight is external, it has momentum in the center of mass frame of the spacecraft, so it can give some to the spacecraft. It's the *momentum* of the photons that does this. A heat source in the spacecraft can't do that.

Comment: @uhoh https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_anomaly a heat source in the spacecraft can do exactly that

Comment: @Antzi By radiating photons away from the craft you get acceleration, yes.  uhoh appears to be saying that if the heat source is contained and photons are not radiating away then the craft cannot achieve net acceleration... which is true.

Comment: @Antzi In "Can the heat from an ion engine be used to provide forward momentum this way?", the term "this way" refers to a Stirling engine *powering a reaction wheel.* So no, I really don't think so.

Comment: Actually you can [swim in spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/886/97), i.e. those rotating wheels can be used to drive a spaceship deformation which in turn can move you in spacetime

Comment: Cats have moving internal parts? [citation needed]!

Comment: @CJ Dennis: Head, 4 legs, tail (unless it's a Manx), all internal to the cat.

Comment: @jamesqf All _external_ to the cat. The heart, intestines, etc. are internal moving parts.

Comment: @CJ Dennis: Maybe for an idealized spherical cat :-)